# How can I inject the default azure function logger in other classes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I´m using azure functions using dotnet core 3.1 and I cannot make my custom logs work as expected.

In my values section of the *local.settings.json* file i put the following key: `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and i read on the docs that the functions runtime add the log automatically.

I can see the default logs on the application insights panel, but my custom logs are not being write there. On my class I did this:

```
     private readonly ILogger<LoginService> _logger;
     public CustomService(ILogger<CustomService> logger)
     {
          _logger = logger;
     }

     public void Test() 
     {
          _logger.LogError("TestLog");
     }
```

How is the proper way of injecting the default logging in the constructor of other classes which is not the function method itself?

Answer (score 1):

> ILogger is indeed not a valid injections. ILogger does work and
> creates a filter of type T. However you need to manually add the
> ability to listen to custom filters (in this case your class) for them
> to show up. you can do that in host.json. Here's a sample.

host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "Hollan.Functions.HttpTrigger": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

HttpTrigger.cs

```
   public class HttpTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpTrigger> _log;

        public HttpTrigger(ILogger<HttpTrigger> log)
        {
            _log = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1484